# Alternative way to have this in mips?

Tags: assembly, mips

How do I do the same function but instead of using `lw` to use `lbu` and instead of `and` some other commands?

```
    .text       
        .globl __start 
__start:            # execution starts here
    la $a0,st_b         
    lw $t0,4($a0)
    and $t0,$t0,0xFF00FF00

    li $v0,10
    syscall         # exit

    .data
st_b:   .byte 0xA1,0xA2,0xA3,0xA4,0xB1,0xB2,0xB3,0xB4
```

Comment: Using lbu there will introduce (or solve) an endianess issue. It depends what you are trying to do: extract data from word (so you introduce the issue) or grab bytes from memory (so you solve the issue).

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
  la $a0,st_b         

  lbu $t0, 5($a0)  # Load 2nd byte
  sll $t0, $t0, 8  # And shift it left
  lbu $t1, 7($a0)  # Load 4th byte
  sll $t1, $t1, 24 # And shift it left
  or $t0, $t0, $t1 # join both bytes
```